# I want my header and content to have distance from the menu bar instead of my screen

Tags: html, css, dashboard

I tried everything I could to set a distance from navbar and dashboard from menu but I have no idea how to make it work :). I'm still very new in this programming.

Also every time I click the menu-button, yes it works but the navbar moves weirdly and wasn't maximized.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#menu {
  width: 345px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: width 300ms;
}

#logo {
  height: 90px;
  padding: 32px 0px 16px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo h2 {
  margin-top: -49px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#menubar li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

#menubar a {
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: block;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

#menubar a#home {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

#menubar a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#menubar a span:first-child {
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+#menu {
  width: 90px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+#menu #logo h2,
#nav-toggle:checked+#menu li a {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+#menu #logo h2,
#nav-toggle:checked+#menu li a span:last-child {
  display: none;
}

#navbar {
  transition: margin-left 300ms;
  margin-left: 345px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked~#navbar {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked~#navbar header {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 16px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 345px);
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: left 300ms;
}

.dashboard-title {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -39px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#search {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#search span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#search input {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

main {
  padding: 32px 24px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  background-color: #f1f5f9;
}

#dashboard {
  margin-left: 345px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 32px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box span {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -110px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

#box .customer {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -115px;
}

#box .box-sign {
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

#dashboard-second {
  margin-left: 345px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 32px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

#box-second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box-second h2 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-right: 300px;
}

#box-second .kalendar {
  margin-right: 370px;
}

.tabel {
  margin-left: 345px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 30px 40px 40px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 50px;
}

thead {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.table-spacing {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

table button {
  background-color: #24a0ed;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.transaksi-icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tabel-customer {
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.customer-icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.laporan-icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tabel-laporan {
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

#dashboard-third {
  margin-left: 345px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box-third {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#box-third h2 {
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #menu {
    width: 90px;
  }
  #menu #logo h2,
  #menu li a {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  #menu #logo h2,
  #menu li a span:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
  #navbar {
    margin-left: 90px;
  }
  #navbar header {
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #dashboard {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="all">

  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-local-laundry-service" width="50"></iconify-icon>
        <h2>Low'n Dry</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="menubar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" class="home"><span><iconify-icon icon="ant-design:home-outlined"></iconify-icon></span>
                                <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="manajemen"><span><iconify-icon icon="ant-design:user-outlined"></iconify-icon></span>
                                <span>Manajemen User</span>
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="transaksi.html" class="transaksi"><span><iconify-icon icon="ep:money"></iconify-icon></span>
                                <span>Transaksi</span>
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="paket"><span><iconify-icon icon="grommet-icons:package"></iconify-icon></span>
                                <span>Paket Laundry</span>
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="customer.html" class="customer"><span><iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-people"></iconify-icon></span>
                                <span>Customer</span>
                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="laporan.html" class="laporan"><span><iconify-icon icon="carbon:report" ></iconify-icon></span>
                                <span>Laporan</span>
                            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
    <header>
      <label for="nav-toggle">
                        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:menu-outlined" class="menu-button" width="43" height="29"></iconify-icon>
                        <h2 class="dashboard-title">Dashboard</h2>
                    </label>
      <div id="search">
        <span class="search-button"><iconify-icon icon="codicon:search"></iconify-icon></span>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
      <div id="user">
        <div>
          <h4>Admin</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>


  <main>
    <div id="dashboard">
      <div id="box">
        <h1>23</h1>
        <span class="customer">Customer</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-people" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
      <div id="box">
        <h1>21</h1>
        <span>Karyawan</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-people" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
      <div id="box">
        <h1>21</h1>
        <span>New Order</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:shopping-cart-outlined" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
      <div id="box">
        <h1>29</h1>
        <span>Total Order</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:shopping-cart-outlined" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard-second">
      <div id="box-second">
        <iconify-icon icon="bi:bar-chart" width="25px" class="box-sign-second"></iconify-icon>
        <h2>Grafik Penjualan</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="box-second">
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:calendar-outlined" width="25px" class="box-sign-second"></iconify-icon>
        <h2 class="kalendar">Kalender</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard-third">
      <div id="box-third">
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:clock-circle-outlined" width="25px" class="order-icon"></iconify-icon>
        <h2>Order Terbaru</h2>
      </div>
      <table class="order-tabel">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Tgl. Transaksi</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Paket</th>
            <th>Pembayaran</th>
            <th>Status Order</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Aksi</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">1. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">01/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Budi</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket A</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing" style="color: rgb(50, 233, 108)">Diambil</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 60.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">2. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">05/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Dibu</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket B</td>
            <td class="table-spacing" style="color:rgb(50, 233, 108)">Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 240.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">3. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">11/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Ubid</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket A</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 85.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">4. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">14/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Ibud</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket C</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 72.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">5. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">18/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Bidu</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket C</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 60.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">6. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">20/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Udib</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket B</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 240.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">7. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">28/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Dubi</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket B</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 85.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Tgl. Transaksi</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Paket</th>
            <th>Pembayaran</th>
            <th>Status Order</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Aksi</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your header as position:fixed which means it's got no height and the content overflows it. If you remove that then set the header to 100% it'll work.

For the main element, add the margin to that and not it's children then all you need to do is change margin-left for that for the css `#nav-toggle:checked` rules

Finally you've hard coded the widths when the menu is toggled, if you use [CSS variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) then you only need to change one value.

I've also altered your logo and logo text to show you how to align the icon and text a bit neater. You can use that example for the rest of your items and the stuff in the main element. All markup changes are highlighted.

```css
body {
  --width-wide-menu: 345px;
  --width-narrow-menu: 90px;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#menu {
  width: 345px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: width 300ms;
}

#logo {
  /* height: 90px; */
  display: flex;
  /* added this */
  align-items: center;
  padding: 32px 0px 16px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  /* padding-left: 50px; */
}

#menubar li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

#menubar a {
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: block;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

#menubar a#home {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

#menubar a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#menubar a span:first-child {
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+#menu {
  width: 90px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+#menu #logo h2,
#nav-toggle:checked+#menu li a {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked+#menu #logo h2,
#nav-toggle:checked+#menu li a span:last-child {
  display: none;
}

#navbar {
  transition: margin-left 300ms;
  margin-left: var(--width-wide-menu);
}

#nav-toggle:checked~#navbar {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked~main {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

#nav-toggle:checked~#navbar header {
  /* width: calc(100% - 70px); */
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 16px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* position: fixed; */
  /* width: calc(100% - 345px); */
  width: 100%;
  /* Added this */
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: left 300ms;
}

.dashboard-title {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -39px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#search {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#search span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#search input {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

main {
  padding: 32px 24px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  background-color: #f1f5f9;
  margin-left: var(--width-wide-menu);
  /* added this */
}

#dashboard {
  /* margin-left: 345px; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 32px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box span {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -110px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

#box .customer {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -115px;
}

#box .box-sign {
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

#dashboard-second {
  /* margin-left: 345px; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 32px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

#box-second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box-second h2 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin-right: 300px;
}

#box-second .kalendar {
  margin-right: 370px;
}

.tabel {
  /* margin-left: 345px; */
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 30px 40px 40px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 50px;
}

thead {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.table-spacing {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

table button {
  background-color: #24a0ed;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.transaksi-icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tabel-customer {
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.customer-icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.laporan-icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tabel-laporan {
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

#dashboard-third {
  /* margin-left: 345px; */
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box-third {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#box-third h2 {
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #menu {
    width: var(--width-narrow-menu);
  }
  #menu #logo h2,
  #menu li a {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  #menu #logo h2,
  #menu li a span:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
  #navbar {
    margin-left: var(--width-narrow-menu);
    width: 100%;
    /*Added this */
  }
  main {
    margin-left: var(--width-narrow-menu);
    /* added this */
  }
  #navbar header {
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #dashboard {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.1/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>
<div id="all">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="logo">
      <!-- <a href="index.html"> -->
      <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-local-laundry-service" width="50"></iconify-icon>
      <h2>Low'n Dry</h2>
      <!-- </a> -->
    </div>
    <div id="menubar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" class="home"><span>
                <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:home-outlined"></iconify-icon>
              </span>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="manajemen"><span>
                <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:user-outlined"></iconify-icon>
              </span>
              <span>Manajemen User</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="transaksi.html" class="transaksi"><span>
                <iconify-icon icon="ep:money"></iconify-icon>
              </span>
              <span>Transaksi</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="paket"><span>
                <iconify-icon icon="grommet-icons:package"></iconify-icon>
              </span>
              <span>Paket Laundry</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="customer.html" class="customer"><span>
                <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-people"></iconify-icon>
              </span>
              <span>Customer</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="laporan.html" class="laporan"><span>
                <iconify-icon icon="carbon:report"></iconify-icon>
              </span>
              <span>Laporan</span>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
    <header>
      <label for="nav-toggle">
          <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:menu-outlined" class="menu-button" width="43" height="29"></iconify-icon>
          <h2 class="dashboard-title">Dashboard</h2>
        </label>
      <div id="search">
        <span class="search-button">
            <iconify-icon icon="codicon:search"></iconify-icon>
          </span>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
      <div id="user">
        <div>
          <h4>Admin</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <main>
    <div id="dashboard">
      <div id="box">
        <h1>23</h1>
        <span class="customer">Customer</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-people" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
      <div id="box">
        <h1>21</h1>
        <span>Karyawan</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ic:outline-people" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
      <div id="box">
        <h1>21</h1>
        <span>New Order</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:shopping-cart-outlined" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
      <div id="box">
        <h1>29</h1>
        <span>Total Order</span>
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:shopping-cart-outlined" class="box-sign" width="40px"></iconify-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard-second">
      <div id="box-second">
        <iconify-icon icon="bi:bar-chart" width="25px" class="box-sign-second"></iconify-icon>
        <h2>Grafik Penjualan</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="box-second">
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:calendar-outlined" width="25px" class="box-sign-second"></iconify-icon>
        <h2 class="kalendar">Kalender</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard-third">
      <div id="box-third">
        <iconify-icon icon="ant-design:clock-circle-outlined" width="25px" class="order-icon"></iconify-icon>
        <h2>Order Terbaru</h2>
      </div>
      <table class="order-tabel">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Tgl. Transaksi</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Paket</th>
            <th>Pembayaran</th>
            <th>Status Order</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Aksi</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">1. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">01/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Budi</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket A</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing" style="color: rgb(50, 233, 108)">Diambil</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 60.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">2. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">05/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Dibu</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket B</td>
            <td class="table-spacing" style="color:rgb(50, 233, 108)">Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 240.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">3. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">11/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Ubid</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket A</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 85.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">4. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">14/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Ibud</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket C</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 72.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">5. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">18/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Bidu</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket C</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 60.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">6. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">20/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Udib</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket B</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 240.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="table-spacing">7. </td>
            <td class="table-spacing">28/10/2022</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Dubi</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Paket B</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Belum Lunas</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Baru</td>
            <td class="table-spacing">Rp 85.000</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button">Detail</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Tgl. Transaksi</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Paket</th>
            <th>Pembayaran</th>
            <th>Status Order</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Aksi</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It fixes everything I wanted and also thank you for the explanation too. Hope you to be healthy